# Always left and right spacing with LMColumnView & LMRowView

Tags: ios, xml, swift, layout, markupkit

I'm trying to achieve a simple layout using [MarkupKit](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit) but I always get a little bit space on the left and on the right. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
<LMColumnView backgroundColor="#ffffff">
   <LMSpacer weight="1"/>
   <LMRowView layoutMargins="0" spacing="0" alignToBaseline="true">
       <UIButton weight="1" style="systemButton" title="1" backgroundColor="left_btn_bg.png"/>
       <UIButton weight="1" style="systemButton" title="2" backgroundColor="mid_btn_bg.png"/>
       <UIButton weight="1" style="systemButton" title="3" backgroundColor="right_btn_bg.png"/>
   </LMRowView>
</LMColumnView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gaps on the left and right are immutable margins that are automatically applied by UIKit. Adding `layoutMargins="0"` to your root `LMColumnView` should work, but it doesn't. I filed a bug report to Apple about this a while ago but I've never gotten a response.

The simplest workaround is to add `layoutMarginsRelativeArrangement="false"` to your root view:

```
<LMColumnView layoutMarginsRelativeArrangement="false" backgroundColor="#ffffff">
    ...
</LMColumnView>
```

This tells UIKit to ignore the default margins, so the content will be flush with the edges of the column view.